# Change Y axis Interval in Amcharts

Tags: angular7, amcharts

Am developing application in angular 7. I have added chart in my application using Amcharts.makechart, the version is **3.21.5**. I want to change the Y axis interval label. Now my charts showing interval in Y axis (0.5, 1, 1.5, 2, 2.5,..). I want it to show (1, 2, 3, 4, 5, ....). How can I achieve this in Amcharts.

Am not trying to change the label with custom value. I would like to set Y axis value with specified interval/rounded value. I don't want it to be set decimal values.

Comment: This has been answered here: [AmCharts - Controlling value axis labels](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46687692/amcharts-controlling-value-axis-labels)

Comment: Am not trying to change the label with custom value. I would like to set Y axis value with specified interval/rounded value. I don't want it to be set decimal values.

Comment: You didn't read the answer closely. It's the same problem. You can't specify a specific interval or increment, you need guides. You can try [integersOnly](http://docs.amcharts.com/3/javascriptcharts/ValueAxis#integersOnly) in your value axis if you just want to remove decimals, but note that won't always result in an increment of 1. The chart may decide to use an increment of 2 depending on the div size. The only way to ensure that you get the desired increment is to use guides.